# Standard Algorithms to implement Transliteration and Transliteration Suggestion

Tags: algorithm, google-translate, levenshtein-distance, transliteration, google-input-tools

I have constructed an algorithm to transliterate from English to multiple languages, Since we should show them appropriate suggestion for the words they have entered, I have made logic to search in that language dictionary.

**Logic** I have implemented to search in that language dictionary :

1. Difference in the last typed vowel and find the words. { Ex :  re — > r*  }
2. Replacing all the vowels in all possible combinations . { Ex : test — > [ tAst*, tEst*, tIst*, tOst*, tUst*  ]   }
3. Least Distance possible words from dictionary.  ( Levenshtein Distance algorithm )
4. Finding phonetically similar words in dictionary.  { Ex : tast —> [ tEst*, tEAst*, .. ] }
5. Stressing the consonants between vowels and searching in dictionary.  { Ex : posible —> [ poSSible* ] }

**Is there any standard Algorithms** to implement Transliteration and Transliteration suggestions for the above logic ?

Comment: do you really mean transliteration? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration

Comment: I think the data structure to use would be a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but I can't give you precise links to algorithms that can do just what you want.

Comment: @WalterTross - Yes exactly. The above examples that I have provided are in English so that every one could understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Recurrent neural networks such as LSTM can be used for predicting the next set of words or suggestions. A training set of English language sentences and supposedly their translated versions with all the possible combination of the words in that language like word vectors can be made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
Its not about predicting the next set of words. I wish to clarify that the doubt is in Transliteration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration). 
I have tried to achieve transliteration through keyboard substitution for each language.In this case:
1. There can be similar pronounced consonants or vowels in each language.
2. The way people try to type word may vary.For “Peter”- (“Piter”, “Peeter”,..) but the result should be the proper data of that language pronouncing “Peter”.

Hence we have to find the nearest dictionary word of that language.